# How to form a string of custom expression/conditions?

Tags: angularjs, algorithm, sorting, conditional-statements, grammar

I have an array that stores difference conditions

```
$scope.conditions = ['a>12', 'b<13', 'NOT a', 'NOT b'];
```

I want to allow users to form their own expression with the given conditions using `AND` or `OR` operators/buttons.

So user can form their own expression like, for example

```
 (a>12 AND b < 13) OR NOT a 
 a>12 AND (b<13 AND NOT a)
```

How can I do this? Can anyone point me the right direction to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: There are many ways to do this... the question is too broad as it stands. Do you want them to drag and drop? Then use something like https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/

Comment: Can you tell me different ways to do this? I'm not sure about drag and drop? Does a div acts as a bracket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/nuettt29/3/

You can see that using dragula you can create a bank-like functionality that allows users to drag in elements.

```
var choices = [' a>12 ', ' b<13 ', ' NOT a ', ' NOT b '];

var connections = [' AND ', ' OR '];

choices.forEach(function(choice) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(choice));
    document.getElementById('bank').appendChild(li);
});

connections.forEach(function(connection) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(connection));
    document.getElementById('bank').appendChild(li);
});

dragula([document.getElementById('bank'), document.getElementById('userInput')], {
    copy: function (el, source) {
    return source.id == 'bank'
  },
  accepts: function (el, target) {
    return target.id !== 'bank'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function will help you to convert string to Javascript expression, you just need to group your conditions based on user selection (and/or).

Comment: How do I allow user to group the conditions they want?